# How can I change the BiDi mode of a TeeChart's legend?

Tags: delphi, bidirectional, teechart

Is it possible to simply change the `BiDiMode` of a `TChart`'s legend? Or I have to draw the whole legend manually?

Comment: Did you ask on the TeeChart VCL forums?  http://www.teechart.net/support/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=1a1731d8612602078ad5cbd2db182005

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not yet. I thought maybe I get a faster response here...

Comment: I'd always ask the vendor first. For a start they really ought to give you the best answer. Are you using the free and paid for version? I guess if you are not paying for support then Steema may not be inclined to help you. On the other hand, if you are paying them money I'd expect a fast turnaround.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually some nice guy from Steema is here helping me on another teechart related question.

Comment: Help that starts off pointing you at the forum!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As a matter of fact, he was kind enough to provide me with a working code here :-)

Comment: Do you really think that the Steema people follow SO more closely than their own forums? Good for Steema that they found you here, but oftentimes going straight to the vendor will be the best approach. The very fact that it was a Steema person who answered you vindicates my point. Anyway, I was merely offering you some advice. I'm happy you got help.

Comment: Hello everyone, Steema's support priority policy (http://www.steema.com/licensing/support/?steema/licensing_support) is: Pro-Support subscribers (direct email), registered customers (forums), other users.

Comment: Interesting. Steema policy for non-customers: "Submitting questions at Stack Overflow with the TeeChart tag"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually it's a very effective policy, as it encourages everyone in the community to take part in solving problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BiDiMode in TeeChart should be this way?

```
  Chart1.BiDiMode:=bdRightToLeft;
```

This has never been supported though so we will try to implement it for upcoming releases.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check with Steema from time to time :-)